# intersection (closest point) of multiple rays in 3D space

Tags: geometry

I am working on a computer vision project with a sphere of calibrated images.
And I would like to (relatively) quickly estimate the center of the sphere by simply computing the intersection of all the rays of the camera direction.

Here is an example of an image sphere:
[image]

For each ray, I have a origin $o$ and a direction vector $d$ such as : $r(t) = o + t.d$, with $t \in\mathbb{R}$.

How do I compute the equation $Ax = b$, so I can use a least-squared approach?

I couldn't find many related questions on my problem because many results that I found are either in 2D, for only 2 rays or between a ray and an object or a plane.

I already used Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) for similar problems (triangulation and the computation of the homography matrix) so I'd like to keep using it but I don't know if it is possible with 180 entries.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Follows a MATHEMATICA script which generated 180 random points `p` as well as directions `v` pertaining to a spheric field with center at `o` and solves satisfactorily the identification problem

```
n = 180;
SeedRandom[1];
o = {ox, oy, oz};
p = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}];
o0 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}/5, 3]
v = Table[(o0 - p[[k]]) RandomReal[{0.2, 0.8}], {k, 1, n}];
sum = Sum[(p[[k]] + lambda[k] v[[k]] - o) . (p[[k]] + lambda[k] v[[k]] - o), {k, 1, n}];
equs = Grad[sum, Join[Table[lambda[k], {k, 1, n}], o]];
sols = Solve[equs == 0, Join[Table[lambda[k], {k, 1, n}], o]][[1]];

o /. sols
(o0 - o) /. sols
```

The process used is a minimum square error from the sum

$$
E(\lambda,o)=\sum_{k=1}^n\|p_k + \lambda_k v_k - o\|^2\ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$

NOTE

From $(1)$ we have

$$
\cases{
\frac{\partial E}{\partial \lambda_k} = (p_k + \lambda_k v_k - o)\cdot v_k = 0,\ \ \ \ k=1,\cdots,n\\
\frac{\partial E}{\partial o} = \sum_{k=1}^n p_k + \lambda_k v_k - o=0
}
$$

and eliminating $\lambda_k$ we arrive at

$$
o = M^{-1}\cdot P
$$

where

$$
M = \sum_{k=1}^nM_k
$$

$$
M_k = I-\frac{v_k^T\cdot v_k}{\|v_k\|^2}
$$

$$
P = \sum_{k=1}^n M_k\cdot p_k
$$

```
M = (Sum[ IdentityMatrix[3] - Outer[Times, v[[k]], v[[k]]]/v[[k]] . v[[k]], {k, 1, n}])
P = Sum[(IdentityMatrix[3] - Outer[Times, v[[k]], v[[k]]]/v[[k]] . v[[k]]) . p[[k]], {k, 1, n}]
o = Inverse[M] . P
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sum of squared distances from a variable point $X$ to the given rays, to find the optimal $X$ that will minimize this sum.

For the $i$-th ray, specified by origin $O_i$ and direction $V_i$, the squared distance between the ray and point $X$ is given by

$ D_i^2 = (X - O_i)^T (I_3 - \dfrac{V_i V_i^T}{V_i^T V_i} ) (X - O_i) $

If we define the $3 \times 3$ symmetric matrix $P_i$ as

$ P_i = (I_3 - \dfrac{V_i V_i^T}{V_i^T V_i} ) $

then

$ D_i^2 = (X - O_i)^T P_i (X - O_i) $

Summing these squared distances, the function we want to minimize is

$ f(X) = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N D_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N (X-O_i)^T P_i(X-O_i) $

Expanding this expression,

$f(X) = \displaystyle X^T \left( \sum_{i=1}^N P_i \right) X - 2 X^T \left( \sum_{i=1}^N P_i O_i \right) + \left( \sum_{i=1}^N O_i^T O_i \right) $

which is a simple quadratic function of the form

$ f(X) = X^T Q X + X^T b + c $

where

$ Q =   \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N P_i  $

$ b = \displaystyle - 2 \left( \sum_{i=1}^N P_i O_i \right) $

$ c = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N O_i^T O_i  $

The minimum of $f(X)$ is known to be at

$X^* = - \dfrac{1}{2} Q^{-1} b $

I've implemented the above formulas with the following Excel VBA code.

```
Public Sub determine_intersection_of_rays()

Dim q(3, 3), b(3), c, qinv(3, 3) As Double
Dim x0(3), x1(3) As Double
Dim p0(3, 3) As Double
Dim oi(3) As Double, vi(3), poi(3) As Double
Dim t, s As Double
Dim i1, j1 As Integer

' actual intersection without any noise is

x0(1) = 19
x0(2) = 75
x0(3) = 40


lgenerate = 1  ' set to zero to fix values

n = 50

dt = 0.1 ' radians max
ds = 0.1 ' radians max

For i = 1 To n

If lgenerate = 1 Then

r = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10)

t = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 180) * p / 180

s = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 360) * p / 180

oi(1) = x0(1) + r * Sin(t) * Cos(s)
oi(2) = x0(2) + r * Sin(t) * Sin(s)
oi(3) = x0(3) + r * Cos(t)

' apply noise

dtp = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(-100, 100)
dsp = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(-100, 100)

t = t + dtp / 100 * dt
s = s + dsp / 100 * ds

vi(1) = Sin(t) * Cos(s)
vi(2) = Sin(t) * Sin(s)
vi(3) = Cos(t)

' write the two vectors oi and vi

For j = 1 To 3
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j) = oi(j)
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j + 3) = vi(j)
Next j

Else

For j = 1 To 3
oi(j) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j)
vi(j) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j + 3)
Next j

End If

' compute matrix P

For i1 = 1 To 3
For j1 = 1 To 3
If i1 = j1 Then p0(i1, j1) = 1 - vi(i1) * vi(j1) Else p0(i1, j1) = -vi(i1) * vi(j1)
q(i1, j1) = q(i1, j1) + p0(i1, j1)
Next j1
Next i1

' multiply P by Oi

Call multiplyv(3, 3, p0, oi, poi)
Call vscale(3, poi, -2, poi)

For j = 1 To 3
b(j) = b(j) + poi(j)
Next j

c = c + dot(oi, oi)

Next i


Call invert(q, 3, qinv, ierr)

If ierr = 1 Then
MsgBox ("matrix not invertible")
Exit Sub
End If

' compute -1/2 Q^-1 b

Call multiplyv(3, 3, qinv, b, x1)
Call vscale(3, x1, -0.5, x1)

For i = 1 To 3
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 10) = x0(i)
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 11) = x1(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

---

This is the output of the program

[image]